# Puma Server hangs on restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Don't know how to exactly reproduce. It occurs on our production servers but not every time.

After deploy, we will issuse `bundle exec pumactl -S pids/puma.state -F config/puma.rb restart` (on Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04). But from time to time, we encounter that one of the puma servers hangs at restarting for very very long time, that we could only `kill -9` and start it again. There's no certain pattern of when/which it will stuck.

Like following, after 15 minutes the restart command is issued, I still sees:

```
$ ps -ef | grep puma
deployer  2535  6533 99 10:11 ?        08:33:16 puma: cluster worker 3: 6533 
deployer  2910  6533 99 10:14 ?        08:31:22 puma: cluster worker 2: 6533 
deployer  6533     1  0 01:08 ?        00:00:23 puma 3.8.2 (tcp://0.0.0.0:2801) 
deployer  9973  9683  0 18:47 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

And if I run `strace -p 6533 -q -f` to attach and check inside puma process, I get this: https://gist.github.com/larryzhao/446234a3af91bec917119494f9bc2384

Just don't know where to look into.

I am running on `ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux]` with `Rails 5.0.5` and `Puma 3.8.2`

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?